# WM_PAINT after some redraws it freaks out

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I am trying out the win32 api so I decided to try to draw a checkers board on a windows, just for testing

it happens that I can draw the checkers board and I tried to implement some interactivity on it. To do it so, I am storing the mouse click on a static and using it on the WM_PAINT to draw a red border around the clicked house.

the problem is that after a few clicks the windows freaks out, screen gets all white without the brushes fill and I can find the window title, it a complete mess.

This is the code I have

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "WindowsX.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

//const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";
POINT p;
void TabuleiroCasas(std::vector<RECT>* rc, RECT rcClient)
{
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
                for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                        int width = (rcClient.right-200 - rcClient.left) / 8;
                        int height = (rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top) / 8;

                        RECT r;
                        r.left = width*j;
                        r.top = rcClient.bottom - (height * i);
                        r.right = width*(j+1);
                        r.bottom = rcClient.bottom - height * (i+1);

                        rc->push_back(r);
                }
        }
}

// Step 4: the Window Procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
        HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255,255,255));
        HPEN hPenSel = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, RGB(255,0,0));
        HBRUSH hBrushgrey =CreateSolidBrush(RGB(200,200,200));
        HBRUSH hBrushblack =CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255));
        HBRUSH hBrushwhite = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0));
        PAINTSTRUCT Ps;
        std::vector<RECT> casas;
        int xPos;
        int yPos;
    switch(msg)
    {
                case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                GetCursorPos(&p);
                InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, true);

                break;
                case WM_PAINT:
                        try
                        {
                        RECT rcClient;
                        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rcClient);
                        HDC hdc;


                        //DESENHA TABULEIRO
                        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &Ps);
                        SelectObject(hdc, hBrushgrey);
                        Rectangle(hdc, rcClient.left, rcClient.top, rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom);
                        Rectangle(hdc, rcClient.left, rcClient.top, rcClient.right-200, rcClient.bottom);
                        TabuleiroCasas(&casas, rcClient);

                        for(int i = 0; i < casas.size(); i++)
                        {
                                if ( ((i + (i / 8)) % 2) == 1)
                                {

                                                SelectObject(hdc, hBrushwhite);
                                                Rectangle(hdc, casas[i].left ,casas[i].bottom, casas[i].right, casas[i].top);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                                SelectObject(hdc, hBrushblack);
                                                Rectangle(hdc, casas[i].left ,casas[i].bottom, casas[i].right, casas[i].top);
                                }

                        }
                        for(int i = 0; i < casas.size(); i++)
                        {
                                if((p.x > casas[i].left) && (p.x < casas[i].right) && (p.y < casas[i].top) && (p.y > casas[i].bottom))
                                {

                                        SelectObject(hdc, hPenSel);
                                        Rectangle(hdc, casas[i].left ,casas[i].bottom, casas[i].right, casas[i].top);
                                }
                        }
                        EndPaint(hwnd, &Ps);
                        }
                        catch(int e)
                        {
                        }
                break;
                case WM_SIZE:
                        //InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, false);
                        break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Damas";
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // Step 2: Creating the Window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        3,
        L"Damas",
        L"The title of my window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 800, 600,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Your user name is very appropriate ;)  Grab a copy of Petzold and take the time to read it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem can be found right at the top of your window procedure. You are creating a bunch of GDI objects every time your `WndProc` is called:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255,255,255));
    HPEN hPenSel = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, RGB(255,0,0));
    HBRUSH hBrushgrey =CreateSolidBrush(RGB(200,200,200));
    HBRUSH hBrushblack =CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255));
    HBRUSH hBrushwhite = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0));
    .....
}
```

You don't ever return these to the system and so eventually you exhaust available GDI resources. Create those objects once only at application initialization time.

That call to `DeleteDC` looks very suspicious to me. You certainly do not need it. Remove it.

Another problem that you have is the code to retrieve the mouse position. You never use `GetCursorPos` for that since the mouse may have moved since the message was posted. You can get it from `lParam`. Like this:

```
p.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
p.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
```

You'll need to include the Windowsx header properly. It's done like this:

```
#include <WindowsX.h>
```

Note the difference from your code in the question.

Comment: Hello, it happens with or without it!

Comment: I bet there's more code in your program than this. Is it possible that the fault lies elsewhere?

Comment: besides of this I just have the minimum necessary to present the window and a method to create a vector of rectangles

Also I have

 case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
  GetCursorPos(&p);
  InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, true);
  
  break;

Comment: In that case you ought to be able to post a short complete compilable program. And then we could easily tell you what the problem is.

Comment: by the way the WM_LBUTTONDOWN is not retriving the right position so to reproduce the problem just drag the window to the upper left so the coordinates match the squares

Comment: Yes I did. Get your point like this: `p.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam); p.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);`  The use of `GetCursorPosition` is wrong on many scores. But that's not your real problem. That's an aside.

Comment: I can't get them.... this is another weird situation.

I called #include <windowsx.h>

it shows the intellisense about GET_X_LPARAM and GET_Y_LPARAM but says definer not found :(

Comment: By the way, this is a fine example of why you should post a complete compilable program, as short as possible.

Comment: Ok, I needed to add the windowx.h on the stdafx header

now it works the GET_X_LPARAM

isn't there a way to return those GDI objects to the system?

Comment: Sure you can return them, call `DeleteObject`. But you must not create them every time the window proc runs. It can run a lot of times!! Create at app start, and return when app is finished, if you can be bothered.

Comment: I would believe that deleting the objects was good enough, but it still gets weird